# nginx rewrite urls not working

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a few rewrite urls from .htaccess which not working anymore on nginx. both giving me 404

.htaccess urls:

```
RewriteRule ^password/reset?$ index.php?a=password&b=reset [L]
RewriteRule ^email/verification/(.*)?$ index.php?a=email&b=verification&hash=$1 [L]
```

nginx rewrite urls

```
rewrite ^/password/reset?$ index.php?a=password&b=reset break;
rewrite ^/email/verification/(.*)?$ index.php?a=email&b=verification&hash=$1 break;
```

Comment: Try using `/index.php` (with a leading `/`) and `last` rather than `break`.

Comment: /index.php did the trick. why should i use "last"  over "break" i don't really know the difference

Comment: It depends where you place the `rewrite` statement, but if your `.php` files are processed in another `location` block, `last` will cause `nginx` to search for the `location` block, whereas `break` will not.